# How does the starting address of the main storage affect the hexadecimal pattern names?

Tags: assembly, hex, ascii

Im trying to understand if the starting address of 0x1000 affects how I write the hex pattern. I already filled it out with how I currently think its supposed to be written but I'm not 100 percent sure if this is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null terminate your string.

0x100c: 0x00

I don't think the address has any significance for starting at 0x1000 other than to provide a leading character implying that the addressing is 16-bit (range of 0x0000 - 0xFFFF). It specifically says ASCII, and each memory cell is a byte (8-bit, range of 0x00 - 0xFF). No gotchas there.

Given that this is a "Hello World!" problem, it would make sense that there's no tricks with the pattern of the address here.

Sort of an esoteric side note... Not starting at addresses below 0x1000 avoids pure-virtual call failures, and allows null and invalid pointer checks. Most systems implement a guard in that range (the first 4096, a 4K page size, 0x0000 to 0x0FFF).